# Convert text ddmmyyyy to SAS date with format Date9

Tags: sas

I have a text column with data in the form of 'dd.mm.yyyy'. I need to convert it to SAS Date with format Date9.

```
mydate(text format)       newdate(Date format)
06.02.2019                06FEB2019
09.02.2019                09FEB2019
```

I did the following but it returns missing.

```
input(compress(t1.mydate, '.'), date7.)
```

then I format to Date9. but result is missing.

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I found that it works if I put format ddmmyy8, instead of date7.

```
input(compress(t1.'Interaction Date'n, '.'), ddmmyy8.)
```

then format to Date9.

Comment: That was what i wanted to post but luckily you got it by yourself. Think 12.34.5678 are clearly eight chars but it seems you counted the number in target format and also used target format. ddmyy8. is the right informat.